# ListView + GridView in Widget

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget, android-gridview

I need to create a widget(for Homescreen) with 2 part: first - ListView at the top, it must fill 50% of widget, and second part is GridView it must be below first part, and same must take 50% of place.

I was try to find some tutorial but can't so if some one do same please help me.

Comment: Listviews and Gridviews are not possible in standard appwidgets. You can have some kind of adapter view inside a widget since Android 3.0 but I don't know if it is possible two have two different adapter views in one widget.

Comment: btw, use `android-TAG` instead of just `TAG`. For example, you should use `android-listview` instead of `listview` and `android-gridview` instead of `gridview`

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a simple layout? There are multiple meanings of the word "widget" in Android. If you mean layout, you can assign 50% of the space to each using `LinearLayout`'s `android:layout_weight` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yea it is simple first part, but i looking for some tutorial about making it for Widget that situated on Homescreen

Comment: Oh, then you should have tagged your post with `appwidget`, not `widget` :). It's OK, I didn't know about that until recently either.

Comment: That said, are you sure you want to display that much information in a widget? Both a gridview and a listview?

Comment: sorry i just start working with android and didn't know it. Yeah i need both of View

Comment: If you just got started, you might consider reading up on them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html